# Convert a little-complex regex to a python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a problem running a regex pattern on python. I've tried it on The regex is working fine on [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) though.

This is the string I'll be working on

```
query = INSERT INTO `dba2018b15`.`Autori` (`CodiceA`, `Nome`, `Naz`) VALUES ('1', 'Mario', 'Italiana');
```

And this is the pattern:

```
pattern = \('(\w)', '(\w+)', '(\w+)'\);
```

The output I'm getting from python is this:

```
None
```

The desired output should return is this:

```
('1', 'Mario', 'Italiana');
```

1. First match: `1`
2. Second match: `Mario`
3. Third match: `Italiana`

Does anyone know how to structure the pattern in a correct way?
Thanks.

Comment: what is desired output ?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/oE82hC/1/codegen?language=python

Comment: I've added more description @CodeManiac

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew add it in answers. mine is somewhat  same as of you. but have added it first. so post it.

Comment: @Moltivie wiktor has already provided a answer to you question.check his answer.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, that worked for me. If you post it as an answer I can vote it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you should put the query string as =>

`"query = INSERT INTO`dba2018b15`.`Autori`(`CodiceA`,`Nome`,`Naz`) VALUES ('1', 'Mario', 'Italiana');"`

these websites takes the input as strings but we have to input a string if we are doing `regex` in any language..

so, this might be the solution to your problem..

```
import re

pattern = r"\('(\w)', '(\w+)', '(\w+)'\)";

matches = re.findall(pattern, "query = INSERT INTO `dba2018b15`.`Autori` (`CodiceA`, `Nome`, `Naz`) VALUES ('1', 'Mario', 'Italiana');")

print(matches[0]) # prints a tuple ('1', 'Mario', 'Italiana')

# later if you want individual items

indv1 = matches[0][0] # '1'
indv2 = matches[0][1] # 'Mario'
indv3 = matches[0][2] # 'Italiana'
```

Comment: Best practice is to use a raw string `r"\('(\w)',..."` for the regex.

Comment: ^^ and particularly *because* it just so happens that it works correctly with this string. That will not always be the case.

Comment: you are right, it's funny that when I tested my code in my terminal i used `r''` and not here, thanks for pointing out.